# CakePHP 2.x open modal box as well as AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I am new to CakePHP 2.x. What i am doing now is i have already done in CakePHP 1.3

I have display all the data in table view. I want to open a modalbox when user click on add and edit button. I have also done the AJAX active deactive and AJAX pagination in CakePHP 2.x.

Active/deactive is done with `$this->ajax->link`

Now, in simple html file when I write the below code a modalbox will appear:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.0.0/prototype.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/scriptaculous/1.9.0/scriptaculous.js?load=effects" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../modalbox.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../modalbox.css" type="text/css" />

<a href="_ajax_content.html" title="Modalbox with default options test" onclick="Modalbox.show(this.href); return false;">Modalbox with default options test</a>
```

Now I want to do the same thing here. When I include this JS in my CakePHP code, my AJAX and pagination stops working. I read somewhere that jquery.js and scriptcula.js will conflict with each other.

I need to use this both first one for pagination and AJAX link and second one for modalbox.

Can you help me to get out of this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should just use jQuery in no conflict mode.

like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.noConflict();
// Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

after it you can call jQuery with jQuery like:

`jQuery(document).ready....`